# Flutter build error at task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug

Tags: android, flutter, udev

When building a Flutter app in my linux machine, I encountered this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'.
> Could not copy file '/FwzFiles/GitHub/nilai_sekolah/build/app/intermediates/flutter/debug/android-arm64/flutter_assets' to '/FwzFiles/GitHub/nilai_sekolah/build/app/intermediates/merged_assets/debug/mergeDebugAssets/out/flutter_assets'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I've had to setup my Android device (Google Pixel 2) [using this tutorial](http://www.janosgyerik.com/adding-udev-rules-for-usb-debugging-android-devices/) (which requires me to change udev permissions), so is this related to the error at all? I'm able to `pull` and `push` files to my device.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same error some time ago, and at the end of a lot of research, I realized that the directory that I created for my project was a partition mounted when my Ubuntu was booting, and that was giving this directory **root owner**, and then, I couldn't edit anything there with flutter. I edited /etc/fstab and it solved my problem.

For your problem I would use:
`sudo chown -R $USER: /FwzFiles/GitHub/[project_folder]`

Then open the properties of your project folder and go to 'permissions' and see if you are the owner of that folder.

And if that alone does not work:
`sudo chmod -R 777 /FwzFiles/GitHub/[project_folder]`

**Explanation:**

- sudo chown -R recursively change owner
- $USER the current user
- : also change group to the specific user
- sudo chmod -R recursively change permissions of files & folders
- 777 value for *read/write/execute*

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just delete the `executionHistory.bin` file from `./gradle/6.7/executionHistory/`